# git lfs - How to track files already committed to a local branch

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

We have a collaborator who has been doing local commits, but not pushing them to GitHub since they were failing. We found that they were failing due to large files. So we installed lfs on his system and added those files to be tracked. However, since they were already committed it appears that they will not use lfs. 
What is the simplest way to remedy this situation?

I tried testing out how to fix this with a test repo by reverting the commits, but it is still stuck and the push to the remote fails. In the above case we do not want to revert or reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have a collaborator who has been doing local commits,
>   **but not pushing them to GitHub since they were failing**.

If they were not pushed they are still private branch which means that you can modify them without any concerns.

> We found that they were failing due to large files

GitHub has a limit of file size < 100MB. In Your case as mentioned above if the branch is still private branch you can perform a rebase and use LFS to "clean it out.

> What is the simplest way to remedy this situation?

As explained above - clean it using LFS and then push it.